# Uncaught ReferenceError in Sharepoint web part element

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, onclick, referenceerror

I have variety of SP pges, which has the same structure and code inside, but one of them is throwing 'Uncaught ReferenceError:  not defined' error.

I have tried to place the script code before the link / button, but no success so far.

the HTML code i have and function i am trying to call:

```
<a id="btnGetSetListItem1" onclick="ConfirmArchiveMain()">
   <div>Main Archive Data</div></a>​></th>
<script> 

function ConfirmArchiveMain(){
var retVal = confirm("Do you​ want continuing Archiving ?");
    if( retVal == true ){
    ArchiveMain();
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("User does not want to continue!");
            return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Both HTML and JS codes are placed in the same WebPart. the mystery for me is why it does not work, while for other pages with the same setup it does.

Comment: Post the **exact** error, including what the browser says is undefined.

Comment: @Pointy, yes, the error is -Uncaught ReferenceError: ConfirmArchiveMain is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Dashboard TAndM.aspx:967)  ; and reference goes to button's code

Comment: Ah, OK. Well that means that for some reason that function is not defined. Are you getting other script errors while the page loads?

Comment: @Pointy, no, this one is the only one i am getting when trying to call the function (the error appears only when i am clicking button tho)

Comment: Right, that makes sense because no attempt would be made to call the function otherwise. I cannot tell from what you posted why the function is not defined, but that's what the error means. You could try adding a `console.log()` before the function definition to verify that the script is running at all.

Comment: @Pointy, it seems the actual error is in another code's part (not in the function i have posted here, hmmm...) ... will try to solve it. thank you a lot for your help! :)